# Passing data from activity (extras) to MessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ok. I really need your help. I can't find any solution so I am open to suggestions.
I am writing communicator (like messanger) app. Everything work fine. I have notifications. But I need notifications to not be displayed in specific conversations. I'm using FCM. I send data and receive through MessagingService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String conId = remoteMessage.getData().get("conId");

    sendNotification(message, title, conId);
    Log.d(TAG, message + "   " + title);
}
```

Conversation is displayed in ConversationActivity. When I click conversation from list I'm putting unique conversation Id as intent extra to ConversationActivity. In ConversationActivity messages listner is listening by this id. Now lets say that we have opened conversation. I need to do something what will let me show all notifications when app is in background and show all notifications except opened conversation when app is in foreground. I have Id in onMessageReceived and in Activity but I can't connect it. My only idea is to create SQLite database and save current conversation Id there but I belive there is another solution. Please I need your help.

Comment: **show all notifications except opened conversation when app is in foreground** Can't you simply match the activity conversationId with other list of notification conversationId ?

Comment: Just store current open conversationId in some static helper field and if ids do not match show standart notification else send broadcast which is listened in ConversationActivity

Comment: Ok. I don't have experience in writing those helpers. Can you guide me in this process? I know that I should create helper class but what then? Send id to helper in activity. But how to retrieve this id value in service?